# Excel transforming columns based on multiple cells data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am very new to excel and was trying to transform my data.

I have the following data

[image: Original Data]

And would like to transform it to

[image: Transformed data]

Here if any "column" value corresponding to the "ID" is "Yes" in Original dataset the value in the transformed dataset will be "Yes".

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  Do you already have the unique ID list?  Seems like testing if countifs is greater than 0 would do what you want.

Comment: Yes I already have the unique ID list

Comment: Do you want to return the first result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365 Excel we can use:

```
=LET(id,A2:A9,clm,B2:B9,unq,UNIQUE(id),cnt,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,unq,B:B,"yes"),"yes","no"),CHOOSE({1,2},unq,cnt))
```

We are getting a unique list then using that unique list in a COUNTIFS we return if there are any that include at least one `Yes`.  If so we return `yes` if not `no`.

The CHOOSE allows us to put both the Unique and the result of the IF in two columns.

[image]